# AVFoundation crash when setting isEnabled on AVCaptureAudioChannel

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

For some AVCaptureDevices, trying to set `isEnabled` on an AVCaptureAudioChannel results in a crash:

`Assertion failed: (pSrcASBD->mChannelsPerFrame == [_internal->audioChannels count]), function -[AVCaptureConnection_Tundra copyPostSplitSummaryAudioFormatDescription], file AVCaptureConnection.m, line 817.`

```swift
guard let channel = connection.audioChannels[safe: channelIndex] else { return }
if channel.isEnabled != enabled {
    channel.isEnabled = enabled
}
```

The same issue does not occur when setting the volume:

```swift
guard let channel = connection.audioChannels[safe: channelIndex] else { return }
if channel.volume != volume {
    channel.volume = volume
}
```

On a slightly unrelated note I would love to know why any issues I seem to see with AVFoundation result in the _tundra suffix. I believe this is the codename, but I do not see other crashes and log entries using this online.